# Confused with Apples and Mangoes.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have got a question with answer but don't have complete solution so don't know how this answer is correct.

**Question:** Two apples and three mangoes costs Rs.86. Four apples and one mango cost Rs.112. What is the cost of an apple.

**Answer:** Cost of an apple is Rs.25.

I want to see complete solution.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer is 25?  Does it ask for the answer to be rounded to the nearest integer?

Comment: Sorry, two apples and three mangoes costs 86 not 80. My bad.

Comment: (logic) is not the correct tag for this question. Try (linear-algebra).

Comment: You can check that the solution is correct by substituting the cost of the apple into each equation and seeing that they both yield the same answer for the cost of a mango (Rs.12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With A="Apples" and M="Mangos", the two equations you get from this problem are:
$$2A+3M=86$$   $$4A+M=112$$
This is a system of two equations involving two variables, and because you have the same number of equations as variables, you can solve for those variables.

You can add multiples of one equation in the system to another equation in the system without changing the system. (i.e. The values for A & M wont change.)

Subtracting $2Eq_1$ from $Eq_2$ will get rid of the A variable in the second equation leaving it as an equation in terms of only M. This will allow you algebraically determine the value of M.

$$\;\;\;\,Eq_2:\;\;\;\;\;4A+1M=112\\-2Eq_1:-2(2A+3M=\;86)\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0A-5M=-60$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;-5M=-60\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;M=12$$

This value for the price of Mangos ($M=12$) can be substituted back into the other equation in order to determine the value for $A$.

$$2A+3(12)=86\\\;\;\;\;2A+36=86\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;2A=50\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,A=25$$

Final results are $A=25$ and $M=12$.

Comment: I still don't understand how did this happen.
$$\;\;\;\,Eq_2:\;\;\;\;\;4A+1M=112\\-2Eq_1:-2(2A+3M=\;86)\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0A-5M=-60$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;-5M=-60\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;M=12$$
Can you share its definition?

Comment: @Murtaza In that step I subtracted $2*Eq_1$ from $Eq_2$ to get a third equation that also uses the same values for $A$ and $M$ ($Eq_2-2Eq_1=Eq_3$). Since the subtraction got rid of the $A$ value in one of the equations, I was able to solve for the $M$.
$\\$Is your question why I'm able to subtract a multiple of one equation from another and still get a valid third equation with the same $A$ and $M$?

Comment: Yes and also I want to know where $-2$ came in $Eq_1$.

Comment: I have found what you did with the equation. You adding in one of the two equations to eliminate one variable from equation to get result for one variable. [source](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics/core-algebra-systems/core-algebra-systems-tutorial/v/solving-systems-of-equations-by-elimination)

Comment: @Murtaza You can add or subtract the same thing from both sides of an equation without changing its value. So if you subtract the left hand side of $Eq_2$ by the left hand side of $Eq_1$, then you have to subtract an equal amount from the right hand side of $Eq_2$ in order to not change its value. In $Eq_1$, the left hand side, $2A+3M$, equals the right hand side, $86$, so if you don't want to change the value of $Eq_2$, you have to subtract $86$ (an equal amount) from $Eq_2$'s right side as well. That's why you can add or subtract multiples of one equation to another.

Comment: @Murtaza Yes exactly, that's where the $-2$ came in. That was the multiple of $Eq_1$ that would eliminate the $A$ variable in $Eq_2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *system of (linear) equations*. You should be able to write two equations from the given information, using A for apples and M for mangoes.

For example, "two apples and three mangoes costs $80$" becomes $$2A + 3M = 80$$

Comment: There was a mistake in question, recheck it please.

Comment: The actual numbers make little difference. You need to know how to solve a system of equations. Here is one site: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin5.htm

Comment: I tried this method but getting infinite result.

Comment: What two equations are you using?

Comment: $$6A+4M=198$$ after combining both equations.

Comment: You should be using the ELIMINATION METHOD to get one equation in (just) one variable. Then after solving that (say, for A), you can substitute back into an original equation and find the other variable.